# Cannot find module '@jest/globals' in a vue test using jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, jestjs

I am trying to write a really simple test from vue documentation inside my Project.
I can run tests with jest in my project, but as soon as i am trying to mock axios request with jest, i have this error :

```
 FAIL  tests/unit/test.spec.js
```

● Test suite failed to run

```
Cannot find module '@jest/globals' from 'test.spec.js'

  14 |   })

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
  at _getJestObj (tests/unit/test.spec.js:16:7)
  at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/test.spec.js:3:1)
```

Here is my Foo component :

```
<template>
  <button @click="fetchResults">{{ value }}</button>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        value: null
      }
    },

    methods: {
      async fetchResults() {
        const response = await axios.get('mock/service')
        this.value = response.data
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And the test associated :

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Foo from './Foo'
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: Promise.resolve('value')
}))

it('fetches async when a button is clicked', done => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Foo)
    wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('value')
      done()
    })
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated :)
Thanks guys !

Answer (score 12):

Assuming that you are also using `babel-jest`, make sure you have both versions of `jest` and `babel-jest` set to same numer (`24,` 26` etc.). I had the same problem and it was because the package versions were not in sync.

---

If you're using npm **7+**, then **peer dependencies are automatically installed** and you could end up with two different versions of `babel-jest` used simultaneously. You [can disable that behavior](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps) by adding

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
```

into `.npmrc` file.

Comment: Thanks for help. In facti removed "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "src"
  ],
  "modulePaths": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules"
  ], from my jest.config.js file and all worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error happens in babel-jest@26.0.1. After downgrade to babel-jest@21.2.0, problem disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Fixed with lowering the jest libraries' versions to be the same as of `ts-jest`:

```
    "@jest/globals": "29.1.1",
    "jest": "29.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "29.1.1",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.1"
```