# TS2307: Cannot find module '@jest/globals' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I have got an error TS2307: Cannot find module '@jest/globals' or its corresponding type declarations while importing values for my default test suit (**but it passes successfully**)

```
import { describe, expect, test } from '@jest/globals'

describe('Example test', () => {
    test('something', () => {
        expect('').toBeFalsy()
    })
})
```

my `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^16.11.11",
        ...
        "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    },
    "optionalDependencies": {
        ...
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@jest/globals": "^27.4.2",
        "babel-preset-jest": "^27.4.0",
        ...
    }
}
```

Can anybody helps me?

Comment: Hi, how is your project set up? Is it a Create React App or did you configure the toolchain yourself? What happens if you remove the `@jest/globals` import? I never manually import `describe, expect, test`, jest provides them when running the tests.

Comment: Disable automatic installation of peer dependencies - see answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61797799/1795426

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module '@jest/globals' in a vue test using jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794923/cannot-find-module-jest-globals-in-a-vue-test-using-jest)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `ts-jest`, the package version should be the same as of the other Jest libraries.

My problem was fixed by lowering the versions of `@jest/globals`, `jest`, and `jest-environment-jsdom` to `29.1.1`, which is the latest version of `ts-jest`:

```
    "@jest/globals": "29.1.1",
    "jest": "29.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "29.1.1",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, with the same error but a different set of jest dependencies, I was able to have @jest/globals at the latest version, but the other jest dependencies did have to match major versions, else `npm ci` would error from peer dependency conflicts.

Changing them to all the same version was not sufficient to fix the error on my end.  What worked for me was updating my `tsconfig.json` to include [`moduleResolution`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution).

In package.json:

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@jest/globals": "^29.7.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.0",
    "jest-chrome": "^0.8.0",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.0",
    ...
}
```

In tsconfig.json:

```
...
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "module": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    ...
}
```

`"moduleResolution": "NodeNext"` also works, but it seems to require changing the "module" value to match, and I didn't have time to figure out what that change would break .